Only 2 Neutral wires in my panel?
I recently got this old condo, the electrical panel looked concerning. The previous owner renovated 4 years ago and I believe some electrical work was done. I only see two neutral wires connected to the neutral bus. Should I be concerned?


Welcome. Please add a photo of the panel. You can click “edit” below your post and use the box that looks like a landscape to add your photo.

Thanks, just added!

Bonding screw seems to be in place, too. So much not good here.

Can't tell what is going on with the yellow and red wire nuts on the left side. Typically there is a circuit diagram for the panel, perhaps on the back of the cover. A picture of that would help us help you.

Didn't find any diagram at the back of the cover. The wire nuts seem to just extend the hot wires. The yellow one connect the black wire and the white wire. The red one connect the blue wire to a black one.

This is a serious mess. It looks like somebody used 12/4 cable to feed trios of circuits. That is a huge problem because if two of the tree circuits are fully loaded and happen to be on the same leg of the supply (e.g. the top-left breaker with the red wire and the one with the black wire two spots below it) then the neutral wire in the cable will be experiencing twice as much current as it's designed for. This will lead to excessive heating and in the worst case, may burn your house down.
For at least one of the 12/4 cables, the white wire is landed on a breaker. This likely means the cable is supplying two 240V-only circuits. In this case there is no danger of overload, but the white wire should be re-marked to a hot color and the circuits should be supplied by proper two-pole breakers or at least handle-tied to ensure that the whole circuit is always turned off together.
It's possible that there are other shenanigans happening, like branch circuit neutrals connecting somewhere outside this panel. That's also very wrong and dangerous- it can cause vibration and heating of wires.
It's also a little concerning that there are no ground wires landing in the panel box - it looks like the cables contain grounds, but they were cut off very short. Even in the case that this building pre-dates grounding and the renovation didn't require upgrading the wiring to grounded, at the very least the ground wires in the cables should be terminated in this panel so that they could be used later. Cutting them off short means nobody can ever use them without running entirely new cables.
You should check if the legally-required permits and inspections happened for this work because this looks like it was not done by a licensed electrician. If the previous owner did illegal work and failed to disclose that defect to you, you might be able to hold them responsible for damages.

Thank you so much for the detailed explanation! The top 4 breakers on the right are indeed 2 240V circuits for the AC. Do 240V circuits not need a neutral and just completes the circuit with two hot wire?

@Qingami Correct. Pure 240 volt circuits do not use a neutral. 240 volts is derived from two 120 volt hots 180 degrees out of phase. Neutral is only added for mixed 120/240 volt loads (ovens, cloth dryers, etc.) or for multi-wire branch circuits (two out-of-phase 120 volt circuits sharing a neutral).

@Qingami - Are there any other 240 volt circuits, or just the top 4 breakers on the right?

@Mark No, just those 4. I guess it looks like the forth and fifth ones on the left and the fifth and sixth ones on the right are also sharing a 12/4 but I don't see any neutrals, maybe they are getting it elsewhere...

OK that makes sense @Qingami, they're using a 12/4 with black-red for one 240V circuit and blue-white for the other, and didn't bother marking the white wire with tape per Code.  Nor did they handle-tie the breakers per Code.   Seems like something else is also up with the right 5/6, can you show us a panel schedule or did they violate that code too?
